# Receiving Fatal error: Call to a member function title() on array

Tags: php

I'm learning PHP POO and I'm having trouble using the variables to the META TITLE and DESCRIPTION. I've checked all the topics related but couldn't find an example close to my problem.

Here's the part of the code concerned :

```
$model_Article = new Model_Article($db);
$contenuArticle = $model_Article->StockageDonneesById($id);

// die(var_dump($contenuArticle));

$affichage = new View_Article($contenuArticle->title(),$contenuArticle->description());
$affichage->setContenuArticle($contenuArticle);
$affichage->head();
$affichage->nav();
$affichage->genererArticle();
$affichage->foot();
```

The variables `$contenuArticle->title()`and `$contenuArticle->description()` are supposed to generate TITLE and DESCRIPTION metas, but they send back the error `Fatal error: Call to a member function title() on array`

Var_dump show that the Array isn't empty and return the right content.

I'm pretty sure it's a common error but I'm lacking experience to point it. Let me know if I can provide more specific intels on my files.

Comment: Can you post what `var_dump($contenuArticle)` returns?

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> object(Controller_Article)#4 (8) { ["_id":"Controller_Article":private]=> string(3) "100" ["_type":"Controller_Article":private]=> string(5) "bases" ["_title":"Controller_Article":private]=> string(22) "Les Points de Bataille" ["_description":"Controller_Article":private]=> string(211) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum" ["_text":"Controller_Article":private]=> string(894) "
Lorem ipsum...

Comment: Looks like it is an array. Try this: `$affichage = new View_Article($contenuArticle[0]->title(),$contenuArticle[0]->description());`

Comment: That works ! Thanks very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `var_dump($contenuArticle)` shows the return of `$model_Article->StockageDonneesById($id)` is an array, with 1 element.

changing line 6 to:

```
$affichage = new View_Article($contenuArticle[0]->title(),$contenuArticle[0]->description());
```

Solved the issue